# Adding custom nsview

Tags: macos, nsview, osx-yosemite

In Mac OS X I'm trying to add custom NSView to my view controller (I'm using storyboard)

That's how I create view class:

```
@interface Card1View : NSView

@end
```

and .m file:

@implementation Card1View

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Card1View" owner:nil topLevelObjects:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

to add this view I'm using

```
NSView *view = [CardsProvider getCard:self.uxCardsView.frame];
[self.uxCardsView addSubview:view];
```

But it doesn't work, I tried some modifications but without success. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to move the loading nib code to inside **`ViewDidLoad`** call of **`NSViewController`**.